# How to publish test results from to TFS from vstest.console.exe

Tags: c#, vstest

I am using vstest.console.exe to run a suite of integration tests. I am following the instructions here [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/12/06/publishing-test-results-through-command-line-test-runner.aspx][1]

Here is my command line (with added newlines for readability):

```
"E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"
/Tests:UserIsAbleToLogIn
"E:\IntegrationTesting\Ads.Slms.IntegrationTesting.Web -Ver_20150206.1\Ads.Slms.IntegrationTesting.Web.Smartfill.dll"
/logger:TfsPublisher;Collection=http://xxxxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection;TeamProject=SLMS;BuildName="Ads.Slms.IntegrationTesting.Web -Ver_20150206.1"
```

However, despite the tool running fine, and reporting that the results have been published, I don't see any results appearing in TFS. I am using TFS2013. I have Visual Studio 2013 Professional installed on the server where my tests are being run.

Is there something I'm missing? Why would vstest report "Publish completed successfully", if I can't see the results in TFS?

Comment: Where are you looking at the results? Maybe you're looking at the wrong place and that's why you cannot find them.

Comment: Well I've looked in the Build Summary for the above build, in the above team project. Is there anywhere else I can look?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but for those who experience the problem in the future, here's what worked for me.

Use the Platform and Flavor in the /Logger argument. Those will tell TFS which built project to associate your test with. By default Platform is 'Any CPU' and Flavor is 'Debug' - in all likelihood your build definition doesn't use that configuration.